# Connect Android application to MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

I think I have configured my PHP script for connecting my Android to MySQL through PHP, basically I'm trying to develop a running app that tracks distance and movement through GPS and can store information to an SQL database.

I have implemented a login/signup class, profile class and leaderboard which I want to store information for SQL, but I can't get my past my login/sign up screen. When I try to type the information for signing up since my app need to be logged into use, my app just crashes.

I think it's to do with my PHP script not quite sure. Here is my login/signup class:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Class implementation: signsignupview
// Login and Signup functionality
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class signsignupview extends Activity {
private ImageButton settingHomeNav;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SharedPreferences to save user name and password
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String namekey = "nameKey";
public static final String passkey = "passwordKey";
public SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Progress Dialog Bar
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Sign up fields
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EditText username2;
EditText password2;
EditText emailfill;
EditText addressfill;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// URL to connect to PHP files for Sign up and Login
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

private static String url_sign_up = "http://mayar.abertay.ac.uk/~1205418/sign_up.php";
private static String url_sign = "http://mayar.abertay.ac.uk/~1205418/signin.php";

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Login fields"
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EditText emailsignin;
EditText password;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// JSON node name
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signsignup);

    username2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username2);
    password2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password2);
    emailfill = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailfill);
    addressfill = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressfill);

    emailsignin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    addListenerOnButton();
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Data persistence
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    sharedpreferences=getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(namekey))
    {
        if(sharedpreferences.contains(passkey)){
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
    super.onResume();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Home button
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void addListenerOnButton() {
    final Context context = this;
    settingHomeNav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.homeImageButton);
    settingHomeNav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, Home.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    });

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Sign up button
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Button btn_signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
    btn_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Create a new function to run in background thread while Signing up
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Home button
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Button btn_signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    btn_signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Create a new function to run in background thread while Logging in
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            new createSignIn().execute();
        }
    });
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Background Async Task for user Log in
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class createSignIn extends AsyncTask<String, String, String > {

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(signsignupview.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Signing In ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        String email = emailsignin.getText().toString();
        String passwd = password.getText().toString();

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Building Parameters
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwd));

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Getting JSON Object
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_sign,
                "POST", params);
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Check for success tag
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {

                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Login successful
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                editor.putString(namekey, email);
                editor.putString(passkey, passwd);
                editor.commit();

                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Launching Home activity
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            } else {

                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Display Toast message - "Username/Password Incorrect !"
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Handler handler =  new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
                handler.post( new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username/Password Incorrect !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Background Async Task for user Sign up
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String > {

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(signsignupview.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Signing Up..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = username2.getText().toString();
        String password = password2.getText().toString();
        String email = emailfill.getText().toString();
        String city = addressfill.getText().toString();

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Building Parameters
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", city));

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Getting JSON Object
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_sign_up,
                "POST", params);
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Check for success tag
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {

                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Display Toast message as success and prompt the user to log in
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Handler handler =  new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
                handler.post( new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Created Successfully. Please Login now",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            } else {

                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Display Toast message as failure
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Handler handler =  new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
                handler.post( new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to create User.Please check entries",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.d("sign up ","failed");

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Funtion to clear the user sign up form
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.signsignupview);
        clearForm(group);
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Clear the user sign up form
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void clearForm(ViewGroup group)
{
    for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
        View view = group.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText)view).setText("");
        }
        if(view instanceof ViewGroup && (((ViewGroup)view).getChildCount() > 0))
            clearForm((ViewGroup)view);
    }
}
}
```

php loging script:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("host","username","password", "DBname") or die(mysqli_error($connection));

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['tag']))
{          
if($_POST['tag']=="success")
{
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);
    $strSQL = mysqli_query($connection,"select name from users where email='".$email."' and password='".md5($password)."'");
    $Results = mysqli_fetch_array($strSQL);
    if(count($Results)>=1)
    {
        $message = $Results['name']." Login Sucessfully!!";
    }
    else
    {
        $message = "Invalid email or password!!";
    }        
}

}


mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

PHP sign up script:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("host","username","password", "DB name") or die(mysqli_error($connection));

if(isset($_POST['tag']))
{          
if($_POST['tag']=="success")
 {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);
    $strSQL = mysqli_query($connection,"select name from users where email='".$email."' and password='".md5($password)."'");
    $Results = mysqli_fetch_array($strSQL);
    if(count($Results)>=1)
    {
        $message = $Results['name']." Login Sucessfully!!";
    }
    else
    {
        $message = "Invalid email or password!!";
    }        
}

}


mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: If you think the problem is with your PHP script, can you post that as well?

Comment: Where is the crash happening ? Could you please post your logcat contents

Comment: Okay i have no posted my PHP scripts, for security reasons i haven't posted my username and password in my PHP scripts

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/), you'll forget to escape something and land yourself in trouble.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Note that using MD5 for passwords is completely unacceptable, at the very least you need to adhere to [password hashing](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing) best practices. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in.

Comment: Neither of those PHP scripts appear to return anything. Also, you are using both mysql and mysqli.